# Integration between Rally and Robot framework?

Tags: rally, robotframework

Does anybody know of an integration between Rally ALM and robotframework?

I'm looking for something that would log test results in robotframework back to Rally test cases.

With the pyral rally module for Python, seems like it could be fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell there is nothing out there to do this-- but its pretty easy to do, only needing about 50 lines of python code for a simple integration that logs robot framework to Rally test case results.

In my case, I have it log results for any test who's name starts with a Rally test case id: (e.g. "TCXXXX My Test Name").

The trick is to user the RobotFramework listener API (See: [Elapsed time and result of a test in variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754988/elapsed-time-and-result-of-a-test-in-variables)) and pyral, the Rally python API.  Key for my needs was to define an "end_test" listener:

```
def end_test(self, name, attrs):
    match       = re.search('^(TC\d+)\s*(.*)', name)
    tcId        = match.group(1)
    testName    = match.group(2)

    if tcId:
        tcr = self.__logTestCaseResultToRally(tcId, testName, attrs)

    self.__cleanTestCaseState()
```

In robotframework, I include this listener file, which also has some additional methods to add attachments and other information like notes to a test result (these can be directly called as libraries in your robotframework file):

```
def addAttachment(self, attachment):
    if os.path.isfile(attachment) and os.access(attachment, os.R_OK):
        self.attachments.append(attachment)
```

This method simply saves the attachment path in the listener object so that when end_test() is called, it has access to the file names to attach to the rally test case.  __cleanTestCaseState() zeros these out so they are cleared before the next test cast starts.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've never used Rally!

But in my opinion, With robot framework, I like using Testlink for testcase management system & jenkin for CI control system :)

You can search in the internet for installation.

Hope it useful :)