# Elapsed time and result of a test in variables

Tags: robotframework

Is it possible to determine the elapsed time and the result of the current test in a variable?

I'd like some tests to log their results external systems, and so ideally in [Teardown] I'd like to know:

- Elapsed Time of current test
- Result of the test

Is that possible?

Comment: The test status is available via the automatic variable ${TEST STATUS}, but only in a test teardown

Comment: That's good to know-- might there be something like ${TEST ELAPSED TIME} by chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The listener interface provides an elapsed time in milliseconds, at the end of execution of each keyword, test, and suite.  See the section titled [Taking listeners into use](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#taking-listeners-into-use) in the user guide.

Starting with robot framework 2.8.5 you can implement listeners in a library, meaning you can build this functionality into a test suite, rather than depending on command line options to set up the listener. See the section titled [Test libraries as listeners](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-libraries-as-listeners) in the user guide.

### Example

The following example shows how you might implement the listener interface. The library prints the name, status and elapsed time, but you could just as easily call a web service, insert the data into a database, or write the data to a file.

#### ReporterLibrary.py

```
class ReporterLibrary(object):
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'TEST SUITE'
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2

    def __init__(self):
        self.ROBOT_LIBRARY_LISTENER = self

    def _end_test(self, name, attrs):
        print "%s => status: %s, elapsed time: %s ms" % (name, attrs['status'], attrs['elapsedtime'])
```

#### Example.robot

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | ReporterLibrary.py

*** Test Cases ***
| Example of a passing test
| | sleep | 200 milliseconds
| | Pass execution | test passed

| Example of a failing test
| | sleep | 500 milliseconds
| | Fail | test failed
```

Comment: Nice addition to have listeners available as libraries.  I wanted to pass additional information (like test case context and sometimes file attachments), which I can do by calling other methods in the listener class.  When end_test() is called, it can take those items from self and then clear them for the next test-- I think its going to be a pretty clean implementation this way!

Comment: can you please show me how to call the implementation as a keyword, or how to pass the elapsed time in the teardown section?